# Window.screen in Internet Explorer and more than one monitor

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a dual monitor setup with different screen resolutions and when I visit [this page](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) in Chrome it shows the right resoltion for both screens. But IE only shows the resolution of my primary screen. It appears than in IE `window.screen.availWidth` and `window.screen.availHeight` only returns the values for the primary screen.
Can I get the screen resolution for the second screen running Internet Explorer?

Comment: which version are we talking about, minimal supported version etc..

Comment: IE8(IE11 in IE8-mode) would be great, but just IE11 would be fine too.

Answer (score 5):

Using ancient code found at http://archive.cpradio.org/code/javascript/dual-monitors-and-windowopen/

```js
function FindLeftWindowBoundry()
{
 // In Internet Explorer window.screenLeft is the window's left boundry
 if (window.screenLeft)
 {
  return window.screenLeft;
 }
 
 // In Firefox window.screenX is the window's left boundry
 if (window.screenX)
  return window.screenX;
  
 return 0;
}

window.leftWindowBoundry = FindLeftWindowBoundry;

// Find Left Boundry of the Screen/Monitor
function FindLeftScreenBoundry()
{
 // Check if the window is off the primary monitor in a positive axis
 // X,Y                  X,Y                    S = Screen, W = Window
 // 0,0  ----------   1280,0  ----------
 //     |          |         |  ---     |
 //     |          |         | | W |    |
 //     |        S |         |  ---   S |
 //      ----------           ----------
 if (window.leftWindowBoundry() > window.screen.width)
 {
  return window.leftWindowBoundry() - (window.leftWindowBoundry() - window.screen.width);
 }
 
 // Check if the window is off the primary monitor in a negative axis
 // X,Y                  X,Y                    S = Screen, W = Window
 // 0,0  ----------  -1280,0  ----------
 //     |          |         |  ---     |
 //     |          |         | | W |    |
 //     |        S |         |  ---   S |
 //      ----------           ----------
 // This only works in Firefox at the moment due to a bug in Internet Explorer opening new windows into a negative axis
 // However, you can move opened windows into a negative axis as a workaround
 if (window.leftWindowBoundry() < 0 && window.leftWindowBoundry() > (window.screen.width * -1))
 {
  return (window.screen.width * -1);
 }
 
 // If neither of the above, the monitor is on the primary monitor whose's screen X should be 0
 return 0;
}

window.leftScreenBoundry = FindLeftScreenBoundry;

console.log(window.screen.width);
console.log(window.leftScreenBoundry());

console.log(window.screen.height);
```

I know it's not much, but it will at least allow you to assess if the client is on a dual monitor set and how wide the set is.

The only f*ed up thing IE does is distribute the resolution evenly among all montors.

So it takes total width and divides it by number of monitors.

I have 3 monitors, 2 at 1920 x 1080 and one at 1600 x 900 for my testing and IE gave the left position as 1745 0 -1745 so yea... something is off with IE in all, but hopefull this little snippet will help you, or someone else a bit further is making semi compatible code for IE.

Comment: I already found that code and I can’t use it. My left screen is 1600x900 and my right screen 1920x1080. The right screen is my primary screen. `window.leftScreenBoundry()` returns -1920 and that is out of bounds of my desktop.

Comment: same here. has to do with the ordering of the monitors and such. there is not much you can do about that. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: resizing the window. I have a few dynamic elements, which prevents me from letting IE handle the window size.

Comment: ask people to press f11 if in IE, might be best solution imho, and advice them to upgrade to edge.  
"You are using an outdated browser. Please consider updating your browser to a recent and secure browser. To continue using this app press F11"

Comment: yeah… that would be really nice, but unfortunately not an option. It’s a corporate environment and those things are out of my control. I guess the users will have to get used to the weird behavior this thing causes. (Does Edge return the right values? I can’t test that here)

Comment: @MarcelB and Michale: Just a thought, how is the CSS `device-width` media query impacted by this bug? If it behaves correctly, you might be able to leverage that in a super-ugly-hack.